# AutofacContrib.Multitenant.dll Vs Autofac.Extras.Multitenant.dll

Tags: autofac

What is the difference between `AutofacContrib.Multitenant.dll` and `Autofac.Extras.Multitenant.dll`.

I fell both will enables multitenant DI support. Currently i am using `AutofacContrib.Multitenant.dll` and is not available in `NuGet` gallery. But `Autofac.Extras.Multitenant.dll` exists in `NuGet` gallery. Is both are same ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of these are the same library. As of version 3.0, all AutofacContrib.* libraries were updated to be Autofac.Extras.*. Use the AutofacContrib versions until such time as you've upgraded your core Autofac to 3.0+, then switch over to the Autofac.Extras version. The AutofacContrib libraries were left for people who haven't upgraded yet.